# Wordpress facebook like box

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Now I'm a complete noob with Wordpress and I've only been following videos on Youtube so bear with me. I'm trying to add a Facebook like box widget to the sidebar of one of my pages and the YouTube video I'm consulting tells me to copy and paste the iFrame code. The problem is, I can't find this iFrame code and the screen he is seeing is completely different to mine and there's no iFrame tab.
![This is my screen]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk9CG.jpg

Here is the code I'm being provided.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/eBootdgc" data-height="500" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: It looks like Facebook has removed the iframe codes for their social plugins, and wants people to use their JS SDK now.

Comment: @CBroe So do I just copy and paste the upper section of the code then? I have no idea how to use the JS SDK.

Comment: Yes, you need to embed the JavaScript code it shows you once, and then the div element where you want the Like Box to show up.

Comment: @CBroe As mentioned, I'm an extreme beginner with WordPress and HTML so I don't quite know what to do. I'm on the sidebar widget in WordPress and I have a blank textbox where the person from YouTube pastes his iFrame code. So instead of doing that, I paste both the top and bottom sections of the code and that's it? Thanks